# interactive point plotting based on user input on one fixed graph instance(python)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Is there a way to create one continuous graph that interactively plot user's input on, without having to create a whole new plot instance each time user enters another "name"?

This is my attempt. It does work but it keeps creating a whole another "instance" every time a name is entered.

```
xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
ys = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']

selected_names = []
while True:
    user_input = input('Enter name: ')
    selected_names.append(user_input)
    for i, j, name in zip(xs, ys, names):
        if name in selected_names:
            plt.scatter(i, j)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: You are generating a new plot each time you get user input because you are creating the plot and showing the plot within the while loop.  To do what you want, I believe you would need to create the plot in one process and feed it user input from another process.   However, I am not sure that will work correctly because, I don't know how to dynamically update the plot once it has been shown, possibly using animation.

Comment: it works perfectly on cmd, but not with ide's